# find and replace regex like that can deal with nested brackets

Tags: python-3.x, regex, replace, emacs

I try to scan a text and replace every `\command{<more_text>}` with `<more_test>` but can also contain `}`. I assume that the curly brackets in `<more_text>` are balanced.

Hence, I guess I could probably write a script from scratch that scans every character and checks if it is `\` if yes then if the next is `c` and `o` and so on until I am at `{`. Then I would add `+1` to a counter if I find `{` and `-1` if I find `}` and I stop if my counter is negative.

However, I guess there are already more sophisticated solutions for this problem. I was thinking about `regex`, but I could not find a way to make the pattern detect the nested curly brackets. There are several question (and solutions) about this on this website, but none of them gave me a clue how to adjust them for my problem, since it is not really a recursion. Chat GPT was also only hallucinating answers, at least with `regex`.

I don't necessarily need to use `regex`. I am fine with something that works, preferable with `emacs` or `python3`.

**Test strings that should be detected**

The following text

`some text \command{here more text \othercommand{dummy {text} lala} further text {dummy text 2} and done}`

should be converted into

`some text here more text \othercommand{dummy {text} lala} further text {dummy text 2} and done`

Comment: Regex doesn't allow you to articulate arbitrary nesting, but you can hardcode a regex for nested groups down to any specific depth. `\{\([^{}]*\(\{[^{}]*\}\)\)*\}` is a single level (Emacs will want some backslashes I'm sure, just not sure how many)

Comment: @tripleee hmm I think in reality I will not exceed 4 levels. So thanks! Still I am interested how one would tackle this problem.

Comment: @tripleee I realized that these kind of nesting does not work if there is text between two curly bracket groups. I need also to hard code the number of curly groups and this is not something I can estimate easily. I have edited the question with an example.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348 regarding trying to use regexp to parse arbitrary nested structures.

Comment: I'm a little confused by the `emacs` vs `python` tags.  Are you wanting to write a command-line script?  Or are you wanting an interactive Emacs command?  Maybe either is fine?  Please clarify.

Comment: FYI the `forward-sexp` and `backward-sexp` commands in Emacs will navigate over balanced expressions in general.

Comment: If you use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) module in python, you can use a recursive regex to match your strings: [`\\command(\{((?:[^{}]+|(?1))*)\})`](https://regex101.com/r/dcW4zZ/1) or in python: `import regex; regex.sub(r'\\command(\{((?:[^{}]+|(?1))*)\})', r'\2', s)` where `s` is your input string

Comment: @Nick the problem that I had with the answer in the link you have posted is that I don't look for the same pattern inside the curly brackets and I didn't know how I can adapt this solution. Apparently this is possible with the `?1` that you have posted. I will try these solutions.

Comment: @phils I am looking for something that I can run in a script. Since I want to automate this process. `forward-sexp` sounds promising, thank you. I will try what I can do with that.
Regarding the limits of regex, as I said I am open to use another tool as long as it does the job.

Comment: @Nick your solution with the `regex` module works exactly like I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek good to hear. that solution is derived from the duplicate I suggested, using `(?1)` to recurse the pattern inside the first (outer) capture group.

Answer (score -2):

This code handles all strings as you expect.

```py
import re


input_strings = (
    r"\command{<more_text>}",
    r"some text \command{<mor{e_text>}",
    r"{{{{<some text>}}}\command{<mo{re<_}te}xt>}",
    r"some text \command{here more text \othercommand{dummy {text} lala} "
    r"further text {dummy text 2} and done}"
)

output_strings = []

for st in input_strings:
    output_strings.append(re.sub(   # This method is re.sub
        r"(\\command\{)|(\}{1}$)",  # find substrings matching the pattern
        "",                         # replace them with an empty string
        st                          # in the original string.
        )
    )
else:
    print(*output_strings, sep="\n")
```

### How it works:

In test strings, you need to remove the substring **"\command{"** and the final character **"}"**.

1. the substring "\command{" contains "\" & "{", in regular expressions it must be escaped, therefore the first group in the expression will look like this - `(\\command\{)`
2. the group for the final character looks like this  -  `(\}{1}$)`
3. combine these two groups with the conditional operator `|` (or)
   and get - `(\\command\{)|(\}{1}$)`

***That's it, the template is ready to use!***
Check it out on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/nVUGyp/3)

Comment: interestingly this works even though your second string is not balanced. However, I tried some longer strings and all of them got cut off at some point. I will update my question such that possible test strings are clear.